# Gender-neutral nouns that are mostly applied to persons of a particular gender?

Tags: meaning

Kindly do not start a gender debate based on this question, but I am looking for words that are by definition gender-neutral, but (unlike 'actor' and 'nurse') are used to refer almost exclusively to persons of one gender.

**Merriam-Webster online dictionary** has been careful to define the following noun examples as 'a **person** who..., etc' and not as 'a man...' or 'a woman...'  which leads me to consider them at least by definition gender-neutral nouns, though two of them appear to formally/formerly indicate gender, and a third (which is notorious) has a gender-specific equivalent:

> Definition of *watchman*:
>     a person who keeps watch : (syn) guard
>
> Definition of *midwife*
>   [1] a person who assists women in childbirth
>   [2] one that helps to produce or bring forth something (help somebody to successfully complete some project, I assume, example: *I am most indebted to my editor John, the midwife who delivered me of this most ambitious novel, etc*.)
>
> Definition of *pimp*: a criminal who is associated with, usually exerts control over, and lives off the earnings of one or more prostitutes
>   (The female equivalent word with a very similar meaning is *procuress*, though its gender-neutral form is *procurer*)
>
> Definition of *janitor*: one who keeps the premises of a building (such as an apartment or office) clean, tends the heating system, and makes minor repairs.

I am taking these only as random examples of gender-neutral nouns, of which I have heard **watchman** applied almost exclusively to men and **midwife** applied only to women. SIMILARLY, I have seen the word *pimp* applied only to men in my wide reading, and women who did something similar were often referred to as 'procuress'. I have myself heard 'janitor' used mainly for men, though I am sure there are many women janitors all over the world.

Other words such as *washerman*, *policeman*, *seamstress* and *actress* would be obviously gender-specific by structure, and probably applied only to persons of one gender, whereas words like 'actor' and 'nurse' which were previously used exclusively for men and women respectively have expanded to include all genders.

Unfortunately my imagination ends there.

So can you suggest any words in the **modern language** that are *by structure and definition gender-neutral*, **but used** to refer *almost exclusively* to people of one gender? Please note that these criteria will exclude words ending in *-man* (such as fisherman, chairman, fireman) because they are structurally gender-specific, even if they may be currently defined in a gender-neutral manner.

Note 2: is there any word that ends in -ess *and* formerly denoted women alone, which now refers to people of all genders?

Gender-related fact: are you friends at EL& U aware that non-Czech women's surnames are suffixed -ova in order to be made 'grammatically correct' in the Czech language?

EXAMPLES:

[https://cs.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angela_Merkelová](https://cs.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angela_Merkelov%C3%A1)

[https://cs.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serena_Williamsová](https://cs.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serena_Williamsov%C3%A1)

AND in Slovak language as well!

[https://sk.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sania_Mirzová](https://sk.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sania_Mirzov%C3%A1)

(I am sure you know this, linguists and serious language enthusiasts that you are, but it is still something extraordinary, IMHO)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59054/discussion-on-question-by-english-student-gender-neutral-nouns-that-are-mostly-a).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Words that are *almost exclusively* referring to one gender specifically

For females:

- **[Nanny](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nanny)**: a child's nurse or caregiver
- **[Au pair](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/au%20pair)**:  a usually young foreign person who cares for children and does domestic work for a family in return for room and board and the opportunity to learn the family's language
- **[Teenybopper](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/teenybopper)**: A young teenager, typically a girl, who keenly follows the latest fashions in clothes and pop music.

For males:

- **[transvestite](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/transvestite)**: A person, typically a man, who derives pleasure from dressing in clothes primarily associated with the opposite sex.
- **[priapist](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/priapist)**: A lascivious person (typically a man)

### Words that have flipped gender from their etymological origins

Definitions from *Oxford English Dictionary*:

- **Harlot** (obsolete): A vagabond, beggar, rogue, rascal, villain, low fellow, knave. In later use (16–17th c.), sometimes a **man** of loose life, a fornicator; also, often, a mere term of opprobrium or insult. Obs.
- **Harlot** (modern): An unchaste **woman**; a prostitute; a strumpet.
- **Bimbo** (earliest denotation): A **fellow**, chap; usu. contemptuous.
- **Bimbo** (modern): A **woman**; esp. a whore.

### Words that have *warped* gender from their etymological origin

- **Girl** (earliest denotation): Chiefly in pl. A child of either sex; a young person. Now Irish English (Wexford).
- **Girl** (modern): A female child. The counterpart of boy.

Comment: Brunette is gendered, as is blonde, as both. The male versions of these words are brunet and blond, though the former is encountered rarely in US English. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/brunet

Comment: @Rache good point, I guess it was written into the definition in that case.  I edited that one out of my answer.

Comment: Note that although a priapist is a lascivious man, a man suffering from priapism has probably over-dosed on Viagra.

Comment: @Cascabel true. Interestingly, OED appears to claim that they both derive from the Greek  god Priapus, not necessarily one from the other

Comment: Thanks a lot again, RaceYouAnytime for coming up with some more, excellent examples! As I said, these words are uncommon indeed!

Comment: Now I think about it, a few 'epithets' may also be technically gender-neutral, but probably applied mainly to one gender. For example, would somebody call a woman a 'cad',  'lecher' or 'scoundrel'? These words seem to be used exclusively for men. In fact Merriam-Webster begins the definition of both 'cad' and 'lecher' as 'a *man* who...' but defines 'scoundrel' as 'a disreputable *person.'*

Comment: I have read, and seen with my own eyes, young men who worked as [*au pairs*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Au_pair) in Italy  ("[ragazzo alla pari](http://www.italiansinfuga.com/2015/12/09/negli-stati-uniti-come-ragazzo-alla-pari/)"), so I'm thinking it's no longer an exclusive  female occupation.

Comment: @Mari-LouA 3 cheers for the men who took the gender out of 'au pair' just the same as happened with 'nurse' many years ago - should that be called 'men's lib?' Meanwhile, taking care of a child would be a challenging task for *anyone*! Since male nurses have increased in number in India in the last 15 years, those who got used to call the nurse 'sister' are now stumped as to what to call the 'brother' -- I consider that 'nurse' becoming gender-neutral is a great achievement for men *and* women worldwide, and same goes for au pair!

Comment: @EnglishStudent the use of *sister* as a formal job title for nurses in Britain is consigned to the past (with *Matron* following close behind - that may be another example for you). So we avoid the issue

Comment: @Chris H in India people have retained the habit, and they really don't know what to call the growing number of male nurses! I THOUGHT 'brother' is the best option.

Comment: @EnglishStudent, my limited experience is that in India people are more likely to use titles in addressing poeple than in England.  This appears true even if they're not the official title someone has in their job description.

Comment: I have (rarely) heard *lecher* (or just *lech* as a noun) applied to women.  But we could open up a can of worms relating to behavioural (rather than linguistic) cultural expectations.

Comment: @Chris H in fact 'sister' as used by Indians is a generic form of address for a nurse and not a formal title, which would be 'head nurse' 'staff nurse' 'theatre nurse' etc which are now to be considered gender-neutral titles. So the 'brother' is technically a staff nurse, but nobody can address him that way! I think they will have to get used to calling him 'brother.'

Comment: @Chris H your point is very pertinent: many of these words are not applied to women, yes, but only for cultural reasons. However those words have thus acquired a strong correspondence with men, so much as to 'almost exclusively' refer to them. The theoretical basis is shaky indeed...

Comment: Race.you.anytime,  your intriguing and very informative addition to your own answer is highly appreciated. Thanks a lot for your interest and support!

Answer (score 0):

Here I shall summarise the very few good examples (of words that are gender neutral in structure and definition, but used almost exclusively **or at least most often** to refer to persons of one gender, in this day and age) collected so far, **based on the contributions of many kind members** through their earlier answers and comments (to which please refer for details)

> midwife
>
> nanny
>
> au pair
>
> teeny-bopper
>
> transvestite
>
> priapist
>
> cad
>
> pimp
>
> lecher
>
> scoundrel
>
> chauvinist(pig)

So few so far!

Comment: I am inclined to add 'pimp' to this list because its definition is gender-neutral, but I have ever read it used only for men. (Women doing the same thing were often described by the gender-specific term 'procuress', as I mentioned in the original question.)

Comment: 'Midwife' and 'nanny' are also added because although their structure is somewhat gendered and their origin is frankly gender-specific, as pertinently pointed out by **1006a**, their current definitions are gender-neutral (*but* they still apply mostly to one gender)

Comment: Wikipedia says that firefighting is no longer an all-male profession: women have established their presence in this field https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Women_in_firefighting That is why doctor, actor, firefighter, minister, soldier, pilot, judge and priest will no longer make this list!

Comment: If you can't think of more possible words, feel free to vote to close!

Comment: If you're just going by "*does the dictionary definition say the word can now apply to both men and women, BUT most real-life examples are still a single gender*" then I think you'll find there are many more of these than you expect. Preschool teacher, particle physicist, mugger, punching bag—just off the top of my head, all of these skew statistically very much toward one sex or another. That makes this topic possibly interesting from a sociological standpoint, but not so much as a language question. Possibly a more interesting, and answerable, question would be something about words which...

Comment: ...have flipped gender from their etymological origins. But even that would need to be pretty specific, or else in the form of a community wiki, to avoid a big mess of conversation instead of solid answers.

Comment: @1006a let me explain: I was looking at words that are not gendered at all: example model, author, poet, soldier etc such words have no specificity to a gender. Now which of these in practice applies **almost exclusively** to one gender? Unfortunately you are very right to observe that many of our choices turned out to be words that were gendered to begin with, such as nany and midwife!